# Using map and zip return an empty array

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

I'm using

```
data1 = list(map(list, zip(*data2)))
```

to convert a lists of list to transpose the list. But it ends up giving me an empty array.

The strange part in of this scenario is the fact that this code work for some files. please suggest the course of action. `data2` is being populated, but for some reason data1 becomes empty after executing `data1 = list(map(list, zip(*data2)))`

```
def file_read():
    data = list()
    mapped_number = list()
    to_be_rows = list()
    #change file name
    with open('iris.csv', 'r') as csvFile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
        data2 = list(reader)
        rows = len(data2)
        cols = len(data2[0])
        csvFile.close()
        #data1 = data2.copy()
        #data1 = np.asarray(data2)
        #data1 = np.transpose(data1)


        data1 = list(map(list, zip(*data2)))
        #data1=np.transpose(data2)
        #print(data1) 
        for lists in data1:
            mapped_number.append(your_function(lists,count))
            #print(lists)
        for i in range(0,rows):
            to_be_rows.clear()
            for number in mapped_number:
                to_be_rows.append(number[i])

            final_list.append(to_be_rows[:])
```

I expect the `data2` to be the transpose version of `data1`

Comment: Could you share `iris.csv` file?

Comment: You need to make a [mre] including the input data. See also [ask] for more pointers.

Comment: okay, Sorry for the delay. I did solve it. ````reader = csv.reader(csvFile)```` had a prroblem in a few files. It sometimes read an empty array. putting an exception solved the problem for me. Thank you!